# Health risks of acrylic mouth guards

Tags: dentistry, oral-health

Are there any reported health concerns or risks from use of an acrylic mouth guard, such as one to prevent teeth grinding?

I ask (in part) because they're often used for many years and they often seem to wear down over time.

A search for information returned [useful information](http://pprc.org/index.php/2013/p2-rapid/do-dental-night-guards-contain-chemicals-of-concern/) which seems to suggest they aren't, though it may depend on the materials used in a specific case.

Answer (score 2):

### Conclusion

As your source points out, there are Health concerns with *some* acrylic mouthguards, if they contain BPA. However, the concerns are, according to the FDA, negligible and propose no danger to you.

**Ask your dentist** whether the mouthguard in question does contain BPA and act accordingly.**

> As required, the Schein MSDS for “Easy Flow Acrylic Powder” listed three hazardous ingredients: Dialkyl Phthalate (CAS# 84-66-2), Titanium Dioxide (CAS# 13453-67-7), and Mineral Pigments (CAS# 57453-37-5), but made no mention of **BPA, the chemical of concern to the consumer.**

### So what is BPA?

> Bisphenol A (C<sub>15</sub>H<sub>16</sub>O2), commonly abbreviated as BPA, is an organic compound with two phenol functional groups. It is a difunctional building block of several important plastics and plastic additives. With an annual production of 2–3 million metric tonnes, it is an important monomer in the production of polycarbonate.
>   *Source: [PubChem.gov](https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/Bisphenol_A)*

BPA affects [postnatal development of embryos](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/m/pubmed/16904728/), and has many [negative health effects on mice](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/m/pubmed/?term=BPA&sort=[relevance]).

As always, *sola dosis facit venenum* (the dose makes the poison) and

> the Food and Drug Administration (FDA) has said that BPA is safe at the very low levels that occur in some foods. This assessment is based on review of hundreds of studies.
>   *Source: [MayoClinic](http://www.mayoclinic.org/healthy-lifestyle/nutrition-and-healthy-eating/expert-answers/bpa/faq-20058331)*

Comment: Awesome as usual.  2 things (1) I was actually thinking part of the question was also that since the guard grinds down, what happens to your teeth over the long run? (2) Great that it lacks BPA!  But to clarify, BPA has been shown to exhibit concerning endocrine activity. Basically, regulatory agencies haven't yet been forced to definitively speak against it; one should take into consideration the history of regulatory agencies defining "safety" (e.g. chromium iv)

Comment: One citation: (https://www.niehs.nih.gov/health/topics/agents/endocrine/index.cfm) But we reviewed the primary literature in my MPH environmental health course.

Comment: @DoctorWhom The FDA has listed BPA as a toxic chemical but the doses that have so far been reported in products are all below the limit. Thanks, I must have overlooked the wearing-down aspect... I'll expand my answer as soon as I have time.